# If you accidentally added confidential information on Stack Exchange, can you have it purged?

Tags: support, revision-history

I added confidential information to a post on a Stack Exchange by accident.

How can I purge the information?

Comment: Cross-site dupe: [Questions with proprietary or confidential information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21938/questions-with-proprietary-or-confidential-information) and links onward

Comment: I destroyed a couple of revisions on one of your answers, which I am assuming is the one you are asking about. Can you check and if not, give me the link to that question?

Comment: ODED SMASH!!!!!

Comment: @Schorsch sharing a screenshot and not noticing an open tab in your browser seems an easy way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't do this yourself. It will be a permanent part of the revision history of a post.

You can however flag for moderator attention, or in the worst case contact the team (using the "[contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact)" link at the bottom) and point them at the information. They can then either purge the revision, or permanently make the information go away, or contact those who can do so.

Answer (score 2):

*(update)* Edit it out from your post, then flag the post for the mods, roughly with this: *"Rev 3 and 4 contains accidentally private information what I didn't want to disclose. May I ask for a redact?"*

Roughly in some hours, the problematic part will retroactively disappear from the post history. This will be a permanent change in the SE database, this is why only mods can do that (it is not trivial even for them).

Also the SE won't have access to the original content any more, at least not in their ordinary ways. Doing things like these - changing things retroactively - is generally not a good practice for anything. Also git dislikes if you want to change commits retroactively. So this is a bigger ask than it seems, and it requires a good reason.

You should do the edit to make for the mods obvious, what exactly you want to remove.

In the around 3 cases as I had to that, all were done without any trouble and my flags where marked as "helpful".

Evidently you should do it only in really problematic cases. For example, if you accidentally copy-pasted a configuration fragment with a private data of your customer.

In lesser problematic cases - for example, you insulted someone in a heated debate, and cooled down you would make it back - don't do it. In similar cases, it is better to hope, that only a few people will actually read the previous versions of your post.

Comment: It is worth noting that it needs 2 mods to redact a revision. One does the "suggested redaction" and another mod has to approve it.

Comment: I flagged a question posted by somebody else which included a secret API key, but I got *declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention*.

Comment: @kaya3 I somehow did not experience it. I asked mods for redacts on multiple SE sites (now I can't remember if I did it also on the SO). If the key is already out, then redact does not help (a lot of system regularly mirrors the site network), it need to be changed. You might know there is currently a "little" turmoil on the levels above the mods, it might make them a little bit more acidy. In your case I would flag again, so: "Please reconsider - it is a secret api key". After the second decline I would let it as is. A possible third option would be to contact the team on /contact form.

Comment: @kaya3 Second flag, or putting something to review second time, is mostly a rude thing. Do it only in 1) very exceptional 2) very serious cases, if you suspect an overlook could have caused the first decline. Never do it third time.

Comment: In this case I haven't flagged it a second time since I'm not able to find the question again (and the "your flag was declined" message expired), but it probably isn't worth re-flagging anyway since it's hard to imagine how it being declined could have been due to an oversight.