# Improve moderator handling of confidential information

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation, revision-history, post-redaction

In my time posting on Stack Overflow, it happens that every now and then I stumble across a question that includes private/confidential information that certainly should not be public (API keys being the most common).

The first time this happened, I came to Meta and searched for the best way to handle this problem. Among the questions I found were:

- [If you accidentally added confidential information on Stack Exchange, can you have it purged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253717/8298909)
- [Questions with proprietary or confidential information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21938/419736)
- [What should I do if a user posts sensitive information as part of a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132117/419736)

The recommended procedure seems straightforward: raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag, explain the problem, and you're done.

However, more than once, the moderator handling my flag has marked it as "helpful" but then failed to actually solve the problem. When I return to the question and look at the edit history, the private information is still there. In fact, every single one of these flags that I've raised (admittedly a small sample size) has been handled in such a way that the private information persists.

I don't know much about the procedure for becoming a moderator. I don't know what the training is like (or if there is any training at all), but I propose that the training around handling this type of issue be improved to make it easier for moderators to solve these issues.

---

An implicit assertion of the above is that I'm actually writing clear flags that *should* lead the moderator to the correct course of action. I'm perfectly willing to admit that this might not be the case, though, so here's the last flag of this type I raised:

> The attached image appears to include confidential information (the `adUnitId`). I'm hoping a moderator can edit the image out in such a way that the revision history doesn't include a link to it anymore.

If this should be improved, I'd love to hear how.

Comment: [According to the MSE FAQ moderators can redact a revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132119/179419) @Makoto.

Comment: Since I don't know anything about Google Ads, I have to ask: are you sure the `adUnitId` really *is* confidential information? What exactly are the consequences of leaking it? Are you sure that it's the moderator making the wrong call, here, and not you?

Comment: Notoriously there are dozens of vampire sites that copy SO content.  I've seen them update in less than a minute.  Nobody can get them to redact any confidential info.  So this just isn't very helpful and makes it too easy to mislead the OP that his secrets are safe.  He'll be much better off if somebody warns him that the cat is out of the bag permanently and he needs new keys/passwords.  Use a comment.

Comment: Umm... I don't know for sure... as the redaction tool is a little "fickle"... Looks like a mod made a redaction request (as it needs review by another mod) and before it got approved either withdraw their own request or somehow inadvertently invalidated it by putting a new image in...

Comment: @JonClements learning on the job those mods ...

Comment: Looking at it another way though... it wasn't in text in the post itself and somehow I doubt scrapers/other sites either bother with images or try and OCR them... Probably best to do what what @Robert suggested and if you're that concern about it, edit out the part in the image yourself, and then flag it for revision redaction... that way - it wouldn't have stayed with the same image for as long as it did...

Comment: @rene "learning" and "job" - I don't know what you're going on about? :p

Comment: @HansPassant I agree that nothing the mods can do will actually close pandora's box here, but it seems that "tell them they're hosed in a comment" is not the consensus way to handle these problems.

Comment: I kinda like seeing those comments, @Ben. Even when we are able to redact the revisions, in most cases the author *really* needs to invalidate keys / change passwords - there's no telling how many people / places have already copied the ones that were posted, and we shouldn't give them a false sense of security by just silently removing the text.

Comment: Like @Shog9 says - there's no harm in giving 'em a heads up - they can even do the edit themselves to make the post more suitable/assess whether it's something critical or not (sometimes keys are temporary, already anonymised keys that look genuine/publicly available keys anyway) so there's no real panic etc...)... You can always delete the comment a bit later or a mod can delete it after doing a redaction etc...

Answer (score 45):

I've redacted the revision with the API key in the image and the revision in the other question that contained the API key as text; not sure what happened here, but the mods are discussing it.

FWIW, this sort of redaction is at best a courtesy - a show of good-faith on our part. As Hans notes, there's really no way to get information like this *off of The Internet* - all we can do is make scraping SO itself a slightly less tempting target for malicious people.

Comment: Should the fact that this is a courtesy be something that's added to the FAQ?

Comment: I don't know, @Makoto; does it matter?

Comment: Aren't scraping clones of Stack Overflow using the archive.org zip file to avoid scanning millions of old pages? If that's the case, then redacting the history could help. On the other hand, if scrapers don't use archive.org, then they likely have an incomplete database, so I'm not sure what they are worth.

Comment: I agree with the idea that this is a good move, but gives people a false sense of security. This is a _significantly_ larger feature request than "let mods know how to deal with this situation", but maybe we should consider sending people a note when one of the revisions to their post has been redacted for privacy reasons -- "You published some passwords or other private data. Make sure it gets changed ASAP!" Possibly with a (moderator-supplied, based on the flag?) list of things to change.

Comment: I think redactions are more harmful than doing nothing. I grudgingly apply them in most cases (except the ones where it isn't actually confidential, or is clearly made up data) because it seems to be overwhelmingly what the community wants though.

Comment: @Flexo why do you think redactions are harmful? Because they give the user a false sense of security?

Comment: @BenP. - that's best case. Since they remove the edit history the user may never even realise it was there. Spot it, revoke it, move on is the way to go.

Answer (score 21):

The moderator redaction tools aren't necessarily straightforward, and they definitely can take a little walking-through to get right. They also can have some fun edge cases, because of their ability to rewrite post history. I agree that better documentation is needed, and that's one of the things that we're using the internal Stack Moderators team site for. Canonical questions and answers have been posted about how to use these tools and when, and that's something we hope to use for new moderators during the onboarding process and for reference when needed.

When handling material flagged as being confidential, how we respond depends on the material itself. Someone posting their email address or a public company phone number might not warrant redaction, maybe just an edit. Likewise for credentials for a throwaway demo site.

It's private information for innocent third parties that we respond the fastest to. In those cases, it is common practice to delete the post first, request redaction (which needs a second moderator to approve), and undelete only when all personal information has been removed and the post is good enough to warrant it. We may also contact relevant authorities to inform them about a privacy breach. I have contacted multiple hospitals and government officials about medical and personnel records posted in questions here.

Shog9's commented with follow-up on the two cases you flagged. Both involved API keys, which are between the two extremes I listed above. Leaking them is worse than an email address, but they don't harm an innocent party like posting someone else's personal information. We usually redact these when flagged, but as he points out, sometimes the damage has already been done and all we can do is warn the poster to change their credentials as quickly as they can.

One thing that complicates one of the cases was that they had posted the information in an image. We can't currently redact these images off of the hosting site (just the text), but I hear moderators will soon get this capability. If I recall correctly, that had been mentioned by the moderator who handled that flag. That might have caused them to retract their initial redaction request.

Comment: I appreciate the extra info about redactions from the image hosting site; I definitely wouldn't have guessed that.

Answer (score 12):

This [has been asked on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87471/is-it-possible-to-delete-something-fully-on-se). I'll add my answer from there rather than have it in another castle...

- Firstly edit the post yourself to remove the sensitive information.
- Then custom flag your post and ask for whatever previous revisions need to be redacted to be redacted.

If you don't edit the post yourself you're relying on the mod to determine what should and should not be redacted. Since you know what it is you want removed and that's something you can do yourself, you should do that. Your flag may be rejected if you don't do this if the mod cannot determine what it is that needs redacting.

If your post is a question, check that any existing answers haven't copied your sensitive information, and try if possible not to invalidate any existing answers when you edit your question.

Note that moderator redaction can take some time as it requires [two moderators to complete it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision).

Even if you do all this it's possible that scrapers and archivers have already seen your post and copied it. There's nothing we can do about that I'm afraid, once the genie has escaped it's very hard to get it back in the bottle.

Comment: Note that the author here is not talking about their own posts.